# Can't boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 15.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I know there are some other similar posts out there, but I haven't been able to find one that solves my issue.

I have two hard drives on my computer, and the idea was to install Windows 10 on the SSD and Ubuntu on the HDD.  I had Windows installed on the SSD and working perfectly, but then I installed Ubuntu 15.1 on the HDD and have since not been able to boot Windows.

I really appreciate any help, I'm new to all this and it's pretty overwhelming.  The following is a pastebin I got from running boot-repair if that helps:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13043436

Comment: It looks like your Windows is on sdb, but Ubuntu on sda. Did Windows have its 100MB boot partition on sda? And you overwrote it? You do have bootmgr in sdb1 and just need a BCD.  So you need your Windows repair CD or flash drive to recreate a BCD on sdb1. Better to also install a Windows boot loader to sdb's MBR and only have grub on sda. Once Windows boots from sdb, run this after booting from sda. `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: When I try to use my installation disk, there is some sort of error for every option.  When I run Startup Repair, it says "Startup repair couldn't repair your PC".  When I try "Reset this PC" I get the error "The drive where windows is installed is locked.  Unlock the drive and try again"

Comment: Cannot really help on Windows issues. But if you left it hibernated then that is always an issue. Some third party Windows tools may help in creating  a /Boot/BCD on your sdb1.

Comment: I think I managed to install the Windows boot partition on the HDD while windows itself was installed on the SSD (would that make sense?).Then when I installed Ubuntu on the HDD, maybe I overwrote the windows boot partition? Either way, I just unplugged the HDD and then was able to reinstall Windows on the SSD. After I plugged the HDD back in Ubuntu now won't work, so I think I'll just wipe it, then unplug the SSD and reinstall Ubuntu so there's no chance of crossover between the two drives. Please feel free to critique/dismiss any of my conjectures, I would welcome the learning opportunity.

Comment: You should not have to reinstall. But it often is easier to make sure each system is separate with other drive disconnected. But be sure to install both in UEFI or both in BIOS boot mode. And use gpt on UBuntu drive either way. But with UEFI, it forgets its boot of a system on a drive that is disconnected. You just need to use efibootmgr to add or update the UEFI with a correct entry. UEFI should see two drives with separate ESP, but it may work better if you copy boot files to just one ESP. Both Windows & Ubuntu tend to install boot to whatever drive UEFI/BIOS sees as sda.

Comment: Thanks for your help oldfred.  How can I be sure whether I'm installing in UEFI or BIOS? What is ESP?

Comment: ESP - efi system partition. Some systems auto label it efi or ESP or system partition. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 8 screeens
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system